# Web Workers vs child_process for CPU intensive functions in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-worker

I'm trying to use `node-unfluff`, which extracts content from HTML strings. However, it usually takes ~200ms to run. Since it runs synchronously, this is way too slow. I want to make it run asynchronously.

As far as I know, my options are Web Workers (https://github.com/audreyt/node-webworker-threads) or `child_process` (https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html). Are there other better options?

If not, which of these is better in terms of speed or other factors?

**Edit:**

There's also Threads à gogo (https://github.com/xk/node-threads-a-gogo) and tiny-worker (https://github.com/avoidwork/tiny-worker).

WebWorker Threads doesn't support `require`, so that's no longer an option.

It's possible to `require` files using Threads à gogo by using its `load` function, but it seems like a hacky workaround.

tiny-worker has only 26 stars on Github at the moment, so I'm hesitant to use it in production code. It supports `require`.

I'm considering writing my own WebWorker implementation using `child_process` if there's no better options.

Comment: Can you explain your use case a little more? Are you trying to get parallelism in processing multiple URLs or are you trying to somehow increase the performance within node-unfluff? How did you envision using child processes when you are depending on a library in Node? Why is standard node clustering not an option in your list (keeping in mind that it really does rely on child processes itself)?

Comment: I'm using Node as a server. If a function takes 200ms to run, then no users can get a server response in 200ms. I want to make it asynchronous so the server isn't blocked. I can use `child_process` to start another Node process. I've never used Node clustering before, but my understanding is it creates a server for each core. If `node-unfluff` is running on every core, then every server is blocked.

Comment: Ok, your question is starting to become clearer. However, even if an instance of a function (using node-unfluff) is synchronous, that doesn't prevent other instances for other requests to Node from being fired off. So, a single user may have to wait 200ms but that doesn't usually mean that requests for *other* users cannot  be started. Have you tested and found that using this unfluff module actually blocks concurrent requests?

Answer (score 1):

You can use require with Workers. In your Worker script you'll need to call

```
self.importScripts('../path/require.js');
```

As per require docs you can pass a config object to a module:

```
requirejs.config({
    //By default load any module IDs from js/lib
    baseUrl: 'js/lib',
    //except, if the module ID starts with "app",
    //load it from the js/app directory. paths
    //config is relative to the baseUrl, and
    //never includes a ".js" extension since
    //the paths config could be for a directory.
    paths: {
        app: '../app'
    }
});

// Start the main app logic.
requirejs(['jquery', 'canvas', 'app/sub'],
function   ($,        canvas,   sub) {
    //jQuery, canvas and the app/sub module are all
    //loaded and can be used here now.
});
```

**Putting it together**

**Worker.js**

```
self.importScripts('../path/require.js');
requirejs.config({
    //By default load any module IDs from path/lib
    baseUrl: 'path/lib',
    //except, if the module ID starts with "app",
    //load it from the js/app directory. paths
    //config is relative to the baseUrl, and
    //never includes a ".js" extension since
    //the paths config could be for a directory.
    paths: {
        app: '../app'
    }
});

// Start the main app logic.
requirejs(['jquery', 'canvas', 'app/sub'],
function   ($,        canvas,   sub) {
    //jQuery, canvas and the app/sub module are all
    //loaded and can be used here now.
    // now you can post a message back to your callee script to let it know require has loaded
    self.postMessage("initialized");
});

self.onmessage = function(message) {
    // do cpu intensive work here, this example is not cpu intensive...
    if(message.data === 'to process') {
        self.postMessage("completed!");
    }
}
```

**Node Worker Call**

```
var worker = new Worker('Worker.js');
worker.onmessage = function(event) {
    var msg = event.data;
    if(msg === 'initialized') {
         worker.postMessage({data: 'to process'});
    }
}
```